# django + nginx + fastcgi - how to keep webserver up?

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I'm running nginx as a reverse proxy to fastcgi for django. I'm using the following command (will switch later to using sockets to avoid tcp overhead):

```
python /home/ubuntu/system/sites/manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8080 pidfile=/home/ubuntu/system/logs/fastcgi.pid maxspare=2
```

I'm not too familiar with django, but how do I reload my project after making changes? I've made some changes to my views.py file however the website isn't updating with those changes so I assume there is some caching going on.

Comment: @Ops - you can scrap this question, I've added an init script so I simply reload the fcgi after making changes

Comment: You can either answer your own question with your solution, or delete it.